How to share the rust embedded hal delay between different devices?
I'm trying to write an embedded stm application in rust. In this particular application I'm using the sx127x_lora crate. However this requires a delay as a parameter so I pass the delay from cortex_m::Peripherals but then this is moved so I can not use it for other devices.
How should I resolve this? From what I see the library cannnot take a reference to delay so it must own it. Am I using the right delay?
Here is the relevant lines of code, I ommited all lines not related to the delay:
let cp = cortex_m::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
let mut delay = cp.SYST.delay(rcc.clocks);

let mut lora = sx127x_lora::LoRa::new(spi, nss, reset, 868, delay)
        .expect("Failed to communicate with radio module!");

delay.delay_ms(1000u16);

This results in a error that I can not do the 1 second delay because delay has been moved into the sx127x_lora device
Thanks for the help!
